# How to create a grd that contains intersected lines with pixel grd in Generic Mapping Tools?

Tags: geometry, grid, mapping, geospatial

I have a sparse sampled line file in GMT (http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) format. I would like to create a grd file that shows how many lines intersected the each grd pixels.

note: I found the gmtspatial command but it does not accept any grd and I don't know how to use it. (http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/latest/gmtspatial.html)

Best regards

Comment: Is this a programming question? It certainly isn’t about Greenwich Mean Time (which is what the gmt tag is for). [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Ole .VV, No, It's about Generic Mapping Tools a Mapping tools